# Download iphone application on ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

If iOS application target device is set to iPhone, is the application will still be able to download on iPad in iTune store?

I am doing this because I want to use the iPhone interface on iPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPad can download your iPhone App, in compatibility mode. It will be shown in 1:1 (1x mode) or an enlarge mode (2x mode), but in 2x mode will be blurred.

Suggested to make Universal build in order to have non-blurry full-screen app in iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use Universal build? It supports iPad/iPhone both.

Answer (score 0):

You can download iPhone targeted apps on the iPad, but it'll run as an iPhone app (windowed at the appropriate size, not scaled to fit the iPad's larger dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

If you make an iPhone only app then yes you can download it on the iPad. It will run in 2X mode and will not look pretty.